# New Computer Motherboard and Processor, no Video Output

Tags: motherboard, bios, vga

Bought a motherboard and processor from my friend. I can't seem to get the video output to work and see the bios and set it up properly. Here's the specs on all of my products I'm using (other than hard drives and disc reader/writer and fans)

- GIGABYTE z97x-ud3h-bk
- 2x8GB Corsair Vengeance Pro Series
- Intel Core i7-4790K
- LSP ULTRA 750W ATX Power Supply
- Zotac N9600 GSO512 MB

EDIT - There is a CLR_CMOS jumper on the board that I've tried to clear the CMOS. Didn't help the issue and still wont show any video output even when I use my onboard graphics.

Comment: is the CPU power connector in? It should be a 4-8 pin connector near your CPU

Comment: Yes, it's a 8 pin connector in. Also have my 24 Pin in and still no boot. @JourneymanGeek

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem when I replaced my motherboard. After a lot of searching and going over the components, I noticed my RAM sticks weren't inserted all the way in, even though they looked like they were. Take them out and put them back again, use a little a bit of force, but not too much. I know it's an obvious solution but it's common. So insert them again and clear the CMOS. Hopefully it'll work.